# React Re-Render-Loop

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dependencies, state, render

I am currently trying to learn about the inner workings of React in context of when a component is re-rendered or especially when (callback-)functions are recreated.

In doing so, I have come across a phenomenon which I just cannot get my head around. It (only) happens when having a state comprising an array. Here is a minimal code that shows the "problem":

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Child({ value, onChange }) {
  const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState(value);

  // ... stuff interacting with internalValue

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(internalValue);
  }, [onChange, internalValue]);

  return <div>{value}</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([9.0]);
  return <Child value={state[0]} onChange={(v) => setState([v])} />;
}
```

The example comprises a Parent (`App`) Component with a state, being an array of a single number, which is given to the `Child` component. The Child may do some inner workings and set the internal state with `setInternalValue`, which in turn will trigger the effect. This effect will raise the onChange function, updating a value of the state array of the parent. *(Note that this example is minimized to show the effect. The array would have multiple values, where for each a Child component is shown)* However this example results in an endless re-rendering of the Child with the following console warning being raised throughout:

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

Debugging shows, that the re-rendering occurs due to `onChange` being changed. However, I do not understand this. Why is `onChange` being changed? Neither internalState nor state is changed anywhere.

There are two workarounds I found:

1. Remove `onChange` from the dependencies of the effect in the Child. This "solves" the re-rendering and would be absolutely acceptable for my use case. However, it is bad practice as far as I know, since `onChange` is used inside the effect. Also, ESLint is indicating this as a warning.
2. Using a "raw" number in the state, instead of an array. This will also get rid of the re-rendering. However this is only acceptable in this minimal example, as there is only one number used. For a dynamic count of numbers, this workaround is not viable.

`useCallback` is also not helping and just "bubbling up" the re-recreation of the `onChange` function.

So my question is: Do React state (comprising arrays) updates are being handled differently and is omitting a dependency valid here? What is the **correct** way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is onChange being changed?

On every render, you **create a new anonymous function** `(v) => setState([v])`.

Since [React makes](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) a **shallow comparison** with the previous props before rendering, it always results in a render, since in Javascript:

```
const y = () => {}
const x = () => {}

x !== y // always true

// In your case
const onChangeFromPreviousRender = (v) => setState([v])
const onChangeInCurrentRender = (v) => setState([v])

onChangeFromPreviousRender !== onChangeInCurrentRender
```

> What is the correct way to do this?

There are two ways to correct it, since `setState` is guaranteed to be stable, you can just pass the setter and use your logic in the component itself:

```
// state[0] is primitive
// setState stable
<Child value={state[0]} onChange={setState} />

  useEffect(() => {
    // set as array
    onChange([internalValue]);
  }, [onChange, internalValue]);
```

Or, Memoizing the function will guarantee the same identity.

```
const onChange = useCallback(v => setState([v]), []);
```

Notice that we memoize the function **only because** of its nontrivial use case (beware of premature optimization).